# File Watcher Job in control to run as many times the files are placed during a time window

Tags: jobs, file-watcher, control-m

We have a utility which gets invoked as soon as a csv file is placed. The files for these can be manually placed by anyone in a "work" directory and the expectation is as soon as the file is placed the next job( which is common and works for all csv file) is invoked which triggers the main utility.
File watcher ---> Main Utility

I want to have a file watcher with the capability to keep looking for the file ( for say during working hours on weekdays) and processes as many times a file is placed and invokes the main utility job?
How should I set the iterations for this?

Also, can anyone please also point me to the file watcher documentation for control m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the job cyclic without gaps between runs, so that it is always active. Use a Control Resource (in exclusive mode) to prevent multiple versions running at the same time.